# Three state Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

If I have Transition matrix

$T=\begin{pmatrix}
2/3 &0  &1/3 \\ 
1/4 &3/4  &0 \\ 
 1/3& 0 &2/3 
\end{pmatrix}$

How would I get the quantity
$R_i^{(n)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(T^k)_{ii}$ I want to plot a graph for $R_i^{(n)}$

for each of the states $i ∈ {1, 2, 3}$ but how would I calculate these different quantities. And is it possible to prove analytically if they are bounded or not.

Comment: Which part of the definition of $R_{i}^{\left(n\right)}$ are you having difficulties with?  It appears to require summing some matrix powers, for example $T, T^{2}=TT, T^{3}$ etc.  If you could explain your trouble in a bit more detail, it might help reviewers make suggestions.  I hope this helps.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not to sure I've been tasked to find Ri(n) for each state but im quite new to markov chains so I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that for real numbers $x$,  we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \begin{cases}
\frac{x - x^{n+1}}{1-x} & x \neq 1\\
n & x = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now, with an eigendecomposition, we find that $T = PDP^{-1}$ where
$$
D = \pmatrix{1 \\ & 3/4 \\ && 1/3}, \qquad  
P = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -5\\ 1 & 1 & 3\\ 1 & 0 & 5}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n T^k = 
P\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n D^k\right]P^{-1} = PMP^{-1}
$$
where $M$ is the matrix given by
$$
M = \sum_{k=1}^n D^k = 
\pmatrix{\sum_{k=1}^n 1^k \\ & \sum_{k=1}^n(3/4)^k \\ && \sum_{k=1}^n(1/3)^k}
\\= \pmatrix{
n \\ & \frac{3/4 - (3/4)^n}{1/4} \\ && \frac{1/3 - (1/3)^n}{2/3}
}
\\ = 
\pmatrix{
n \\ & 3(1 - (3/4)^{n-1}) \\ && \frac 12(1 - (1/3)^{n-1})
}.
$$
Once $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are calculated, we have
$$
[PMP^{-1}]_{ii} = e_i^TP M P^{-1}e_i = (P^Te_i)^T M (P^{-1}e_i).
$$
Note that for any matrix $A$, $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$.  You can now get your formula noting that
$$
P^T = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&0\\-5&3&5}, \qquad 
P^{-1} = \frac 1{10}
\pmatrix{5&0&5\\
-2&10&-8\\
-1&0&1}.
$$

---

For for $i = 1$, use the first columns:
$$
R_1^{(n)} = \frac 1{10}\pmatrix{1&0&-5}\pmatrix{
n \\ & 3(1 - (3/4)^{n-1}) \\ && \frac 12(1 - (1/3)^{n-1})
}\pmatrix{5\\-2\\-1} 
\\= \frac {1\cdot 5}{10}n + \frac {0\cdot(-2)}{10}\cdot 3(1 - (3/4)^{n-1})
+ \frac{(-5) \cdot (-1)}{10}\cdot \frac 12(1 - (1/3)^{n-1})
$$

Comment: Hi thank you so Ri(n) is equal to $(P^Te_i)^TM(P^-1e_i)$? but I'd just like to how to get Ri(n) for different state values. It would be so appreciated if you could show me Ri(n) for ∈1,2 so that I can try do ∈3 by myself I'm just a bit confused on what $e_i$ is and how that translates

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: To answer your second question $e_i$ is the $i$th column of the identity matrix.  So for instance, $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T$.

Comment: Hi thanks Im a bit confused where you got the (1 1 1) for in R1(n) would R2(N) be $1/10$ $(0 1 0)M$ $(0 10  0)^T$

Comment: Oh you're right; I accidentally looked at $P$ instead. See my latest edit.

Comment: It looks to me like you're taking the first column for P^T and P^-1 for i=1 would i take the second column for i=2 and keep M the same

Comment: Yes that's exactly the idea.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your explanation, sorry to add but you seem so knowledgable, is it possible to show that these Ri(n) we are getting are bounded or diverge as n increases, and what recurrence properties are.

Comment: You'll notice that every $R_i$ has the form 
$$
R_i^{(n)} = c_1 n + c_2(1 - (3/4)^n) + c_3 (1 - (1/3)n).
$$
It's easy to show that the above will converge if and only if $c_1 = 0$.  Consequently, you should find that $R_1$ and $R_3$ diverge and that $R_2$ converges.

Comment: that makes sense thank you, its n or n-1 like you have above

Comment: Those exponents should be $n-1$, as you said, and that last $n$ should be an exponent

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to say about recurrence properties here

Comment: that's ok thank you so much for your help maybe there are recurrence properties for the original transition matrix

Comment: Sure, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we have
$$
T^k = \frac 1{12}(25T^{k-1} - 16T^{k-2} + 3T^{k-3}), \quad k \geq 3.
$$
The same recurrence applies to all entries of $T^k$.